# I deleted an google workspace account and all website linked are down. How to restore the account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, workspace

I deleted an google workspace account and now all the google cloud information that was linked to the account has been deleted to. Is there any way of getting this google cloud data back?

Answer (score 1):

If it is less than 20 days then following link might help you
https://support.google.com/a/answer/1397578?hl=en